# Symfony YAML Dumper - How to print double quotes

Tags: php, symfony, yaml

I'm using the YAML component from Symfony to print(dump) a php array in to a yaml file.

```
$config["hosts"] = "";
$dumper = new Dumper();
$yaml = $dumper->dump($config, 2);
file_put_contents($file, $yaml);
```

On the yaml file I need to see something like:

```
hosts: ""
```

Instead it prints out as

```
hosts: ''
```

How can I print the double quotes without a string? I took a look into http://api.symfony.com/2.7/Symfony/Component/Yaml/Escaper.html but this requires a string.

Comment: Does it matter? What's wrong with `host: ''`. the value is an empty string in both cases...

Comment: It does, this is a config file for Ejabberd. When I manually change single quotes to double quotes it works